# passing ... parameters at DEFINE macro in C

Tags: c, macros

```
#define MY_PRINT(_format, ...) printf("MIME : %s" _format, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__);
```

and I'd like to add `"\n` " at the end of print message.

But,

```
#define MY_PRINT_LN(_format, ...) MY_PRINT(_format "\n", ...)
```

has compile error. how to pass `...` parameter at define macro?

Answer (score 4):

You use `__VA_ARGS__`:

```
#define MY_PRINT_LN(_format, ...) MY_PRINT(_format "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
```

This is standardized as of C99.

If there are no arguments, you'll have a redundant comma at the end, though. There's no standard solution, but GCC (and possibly other compilers) offers an extension:

```
#define MY_PRINT_LN(_format, ...) MY_PRINT(_format "\n", ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

With the extra `##`, the final comma is removed if there are no arguments.